# How can I check, if the type is unsigned or not?

Tags: d

I want check, if the type is `byte/short/int/long` or it is `ubyte/ushort/uint/ulong`. The first idea was to use construction `is(T1:T2)`, but `is(ulong:long)==is(long:ulong)==true`, so it is not the way.

Now I'm using something like `is(T:long) && (cast(T)(-1)<cast(T)(1))`, but this code seems ugly to me.

So is there more elegant logic statement returning `true` only if the type is unsigned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a template in `std.traits` that does what you want:
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#.isUnsigned

Use it like:

```
if(isUnsigned!T1) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you already know the type is numeric, an alternative is `T1.min == 0`.

Comment: My better than using traits! :)